# Visual Studio 2015 Community start page stuck at license has gone stale?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Created this `NameVisualStudio@outlook.com` account a year ago and and has been working to sign in for `Visual Studio 2015 Community`, but now suddenly from no where Visual Studio is showing `license has gone stale...` message and am stuck there. I don't remember password for this account. So I cannot even switch to another account as I have to sign out from the existing one but existing one is not working. Any idea to get through this problem?

Here is the screen-cast;
[image]

Comment: For reference if anyone else is looking for an answer, http://dineshvr.blogspot.com/2016/08/visual-studio-message-your-license-has.html has a workaround that might work for some.

Answer (score 2):

Could you do the following try do resolve your issue:

1. Open visual studio, then open `File->Account Settings`... dialog.
2. Sign out and close your VS.
3. Delete `%localappdata%.IdentityService` and `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VSCommon\OnlineLicensing`
4. Start VS and sign in

Comment: Basically this removes any account info VS (and possibly other software) has. Which indeed works to solve problems like this, e.g. I had a stale license for VS Community 2017 and the login page appeared but after entering password it just appeared again saying there was a connection problem. Deleting all info just allowed me to sign in again which worked from the first try